# Does IPV6 matter when choosing a new switch for home network?

Tags: switch, ipv6, home-networking

Looking to upgrade my Fast Ethernet home network switch to a Gigabit Ethernet switch.  Figured I should make sure that the new device supports IPV6, but in looking at the specs of a few switches, I could not find any references to IPV6.  I found such info conspicuous when looking at the specs for routers and cable modems, and was surprised it wasn't the same for switches.  Do switches just handle IPV6 transparently?

Comment: I found that my switch was not passing along the multicast traffic necessary for neighbour discovery protocol to work. A firmware upgrade fixed the issue, but it does show that you can't just assume a switch will work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Switches are layer 2 devices, and neither know nor care about what's going on with IP (V4 or V6) and TCP at layers 3 and 4. They just move Ethernet packets around.

Comment: Assuming a unmanaged switch of course.